# Integrating Paypal with php(DoDirectMethod)

Tags: php, paypal

i was following [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/) guide to integrate paypal. I dont want user to redirect to paypal for making payment. So i need to follow Direct Payment method.

What i understood from that guide was that first i need to create two Sandbox accounts(buyer and merchant). Then used details(USR, 'PWD', 'SIGNATURE') of merchant account in a class. So i created a class(paypal.php) and then process payment via that class. i alds downloaded `cacert.pem` that the class needs.

This is my class

```
<?php

class Paypal {


   /**
    * Last error message(s)
    * @var array
    */
   protected $_errors = array();

   /**
    * API Credentials
    * Use the correct credentials for the environment in use (Live / Sandbox)
    * @var array
    */
   protected $_credentials = array(
      'USER' => 'kanavk-facilitator_api1.ocodewire.com',
      'PWD' => '1404460510',
      'SIGNATURE' => 'A4sylwT.LsGOlR5e0Qos27RoSta5AKLvXCCjXXHcGN8Tor8.JxNZxIAs',
   );

   /**
    * API endpoint
    * Live - https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    * Sandbox - https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    * @var string
    */
   protected $_endPoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

   /**
    * API Version
    * @var string
    */
   protected $_version = '74.0';

   /**
    * Make API request
    *
    * @param string $method string API method to request
    * @param array $params Additional request parameters
    * @return array / boolean Response array / boolean false on failure
    */
   public function request($method,$params = array()) {
      $this -> _errors = array();
      if( empty($method) ) { //Check if API method is not empty
         $this -> _errors = array('API method is missing');
         return false;
      }

      //Our request parameters
      $requestParams = array(
         'METHOD' => $method,
         'VERSION' => $this -> _version
      ) + $this -> _credentials;

      //Building our NVP string
      $request = http_build_query($requestParams + $params);

      //cURL settings
      $curlOptions = array (
         CURLOPT_URL => $this -> _endPoint,
         CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
         CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', //CA cert file
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
         CURLOPT_POST => 1,
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
      );

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOptions);

      //Sending our request - $response will hold the API response
      $response = curl_exec($ch);

      //Checking for cURL errors
      if (curl_errno($ch)) {
         $this -> _errors = curl_error($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return false;
         //Handle errors
      } else  {
         curl_close($ch);
         $responseArray = array();
         parse_str($response,$responseArray); // Break the NVP string to an array
         return $responseArray;
      }
   }
}

?>
```

The i created a script for processing form. Included that class and tried to process payment with dummy inputs. But nothing is happening when i'm executing the script.

this is my script that i'm using for processing form

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php");
    include("includes/paypal.php");
    @session_start();
    include("steps.php");
    error_reporting(0);

$requestParams = array(
   'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale'
);

$creditCardDetails = array(
   'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'Visa',
   'ACCT' => '4929802607281663',
   'EXPDATE' => '062012',
   'CVV2' => '984'
);

$payerDetails = array(
   'FIRSTNAME' => 'John',
   'LASTNAME' => 'Doe',
   'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
   'STATE' => 'NY',
   'CITY' => 'New York',
   'STREET' => '14 Argyle Rd.',
   'ZIP' => '10010'
);

$orderParams = array(
   'AMT' => '500',
   'ITEMAMT' => '496',
   'SHIPPINGAMT' => '4',
   'CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP'
);

$item = array(
   'L_NAME0' => 'iPhone',
   'L_DESC0' => 'White iPhone, 16GB',
   'L_AMT0' => '496',
   'L_QTY0' => '1'
);

$paypal = new Paypal();



$response = $paypal -> request('DoDirectPayment',
   $requestParams + $creditCardDetails + $payerDetails + $orderParams + $item
);



if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { // Payment successful
   // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
   $transactionId = $response['TRANSACTIONID'];

}else echo "failed";

?>
```

I'm scratching my head from the last four hours,  following various guides and tutorials but don't know whats's wrong. Is there any other step/files i need to follow/download?

P.S. I'm trying paypal integration for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with [PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php)
Just integrate it in your code and Use this class

```
 /* Created By RAJA */

 require realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'paymentconfig.php');
 require realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . '/PayPalSDK/vendor/autoload.php');

 use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
 use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
 use PayPal\Api\Amount;
 use PayPal\Api\Details;
 use PayPal\Api\Item;
 use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
 use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
 use PayPal\Api\Payer;
 use PayPal\Api\Payment;
 use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
 use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
 use PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException;

 class PaymentProcessor {

public static function proceedCreditCardTransaction($cardNumber, $cardType, $cardExpMonth, $cardExpYear, $firstName, $lastName, $amountToPay, $description, $currency = CURRENCY) {

    if (!isset($cardNumber) || strlen($cardNumber) <= 10) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid CardNumber : " . $cardNumber);
    }if (!isset($cardType) || strlen($cardType) <= 0) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid CardType : " . $cardType);
    }if (!isset($cardExpMonth) || intval($cardExpMonth) <= 0 || intval($cardExpMonth) > 12) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Card Expire Month : " . $cardExpMonth);
    }if (!isset($cardExpYear) || strlen($cardExpYear) <= 2) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Card Expire Year : " . $cardExpYear);
    }if (!isset($firstName) || strlen($firstName) <= 0) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid First Name : " . $firstName);
    }if (!isset($lastName)) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Last Name : " . $lastName);
    }if (!isset($amountToPay) || strlen($amountToPay) <= 0 || intval($amountToPay) <= 0) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Amount : " . $amountToPay);
    }if (!isset($currency) || strlen($currency) <= 0) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Currency : " . $currency);
    }if (!isset($description) || strlen($description) <= 0) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Description : " . $description);
    }

    $sdkConfig = array(
        "mode" => "sandbox"
    );

    $cred = new OAuthTokenCredential(CLIENT_ID, SECRET, $sdkConfig);

    $apiContext = new ApiContext($cred, 'Request' . time());
    $apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);

    $card = new CreditCard();
    $card->setType($cardType);
    $card->setNumber($cardNumber);
    $card->setExpire_month($cardExpMonth);
    $card->setExpire_year($cardExpYear);
    $card->setFirst_name($firstName);
    $card->setLast_name($lastName);

    $fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
    $fundingInstrument->setCredit_card($card);

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPayment_method("credit_card");
    $payer->setFunding_instruments(array($fundingInstrument));

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency($currency);
    $amount->setTotal($amountToPay);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription($description);

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale");
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
        return new PaymentParser($payment->toArray());
    } catch (PPConnectionException $ex) {
        throw new Exception($ex->getData());
    }
    //echo json_encode($payment->toArray());        
}

public static function proceedPaypalTransaction($amountToPay, $itemName, $description, $currency = CURRENCY) {

    $sdkConfig = array(
        "mode" => "sandbox"
    );

    $cred = new OAuthTokenCredential(CLIENT_ID, SECRET, $sdkConfig);
    $apiContext = new ApiContext($cred, 'Request' . time());
    $apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $item1 = new Item();
    $item1->setName($itemName)
            ->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($amountToPay);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item1));

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setTotal($amountToPay);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription($description);

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($ex->getData());
        exit(1);
    }
}

 }
```

PAYMENTCONFIG.PHP

```
define("CURRENCY","USD");

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/PayPalSDK/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    echo "The 'vendor' folder is missing. You must run 'composer update' to resolve     application dependencies.\nPlease see the README for more information.\n";
exit(1);
}
define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . '/PayPalSDK/sdk_config.ini'));
define('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_ID');
define('SECRET', 'SECRET');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have enter wrong Expire Date of `$creditCardDetails` in process form,(put 'EXPDATE'=>'062020')

and do following change in process form,

From

```
if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { // Payment successful
   // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
   $transactionId = $response['TRANSACTIONID'];

}else echo "Failed";
```

to

```
if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { // Payment successful
    // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
    $transactionId = $response['TRANSACTIONID'];    
}else{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
}
```

after this you will get following error,

**ERROR: 10501 Invalid Configuration.
This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.**

To solve this error you have accepted the "**PayPal Payments Pro**" agreement in your PayPal account after you have been approved by PayPal for PayPal Payments Pro. If you have accepted their agreement but are still getting this error, PayPal also occasionally acknowledges the agreement and activates Virtual Terminal but somehow misses activating PayPal Payments Pro itself; if your PayPal "Get Started" summary screen only shows Virtual Terminal and nothing about PayPal Payments Pro, please contact PayPal support to get your PayPal Payments Pro service activated.

If you are only using PayPal Payments Standard with a regular PayPal personal, Business or Premier account (i.e., if you have not upgraded to PayPal Payments Pro), please go to Seller Admin > Payment Preferences and make sure you have PayPal Payments Standard checked (rather than PayPal Payments Pro) and click Submit to save any changes you make.

Without accepting of **PayPal Payments Pro** you cant use Do Direct Method.

Comment: I changed expiry to 062014, but still it doesn't show any error. i tried print_r($paypal), right after i have created instance of Paypal class and it showed values `Paypal Object ( [_errors:protected] => Array ( ) [_credentials:protected] => Array ( [USER] => kanavk-facilitator_api1.ocodewire.com [PWD] => 1404460510 [SIGNATURE] => A4sylwT.LsGOlR5e0Qos27RoSta5AKLvXCCjXXHcGN8Tor8.JxNZxIAs ) [_endPoint:protected] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp [_version:protected] => 74.0 )`. But there is no error. Page is blank. Do i need to include any sdk or any other files?

Comment: I edited my comment, check again and replace code as suggested , after that you will get actual error message.

Comment: I'm opening script(the one with card details) directly via browser. There is no form involved. Do i need to follow POST method?

Comment: find the `$creditCardDetails` in second php file and replace `'EXPDATE' => '062012',`  with `'EXPDATE' => '062020',` . Then check replace code as mention in answer post.

Comment: Did you print   `echo "<pre>";print_r($response);` at the end ?